# Assign multiple photos to blog article in Shopify

Tags: object, shopify, liquid, blogs

Is it possible to extend Shopify objects in Liquid? I'm trying to find a way to have there be more than 1 photo associated with articles belonging to a specific blog. I know I can allow users to upload more photos using the settings schema, but I need to access the photo URLs outside of the Blog template/section the same way I'm able to access its direct properties (something like article.images[2]). My understanding is that anything saved from Settings is only accessible from within the Section in which it was defined. Is that accurate?

I have the idea of saving a list of URLs as the article's content and just parse them out of article.content (and hide the list using CSS when the page is displayed), but I'm not seeing any way to do the parsing (no regEx).

I thought of using tags too, but there will be hundreds of articles and potentially several images associated with each article. I"m not sure if there is a max number of tags, but even if there isn't, it seems hack-y (and probably a bit inefficient to create tags that aren't shared by multiple articles. IDK...

Does anyone have any ideas for a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Metafields are done for these type of cases:
https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-01/objects/metafield